# Modal error document.ready ok href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to include a warning before the user enters my website and wanted to use a modal window when the document is ready.

Here is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.noConflict();
    $("#openModal").modal('show');
});
```

the HTML:

```
<a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a>

<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
    <div>
        <p>blah blah</p>
        <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">I agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The modal window opens OK when I click the link so I'm happy with the CSS. I get the following error messages when I try to open it through document ready:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

and  when I remove the `jQuery.noConflict();` line I get the following error message:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function

I've tried a couple of versions of JQuery and best I can tell that is the latest which I downloaded and installed. The rest of the heavily laden JQuery and Javascript works OK.

As I said in my previous question, I'm a hobbyist and my free advertisement free website is to be used as a sailing navigation aid.

Many thanks in advance,

Simon

Comment: You include jQuery library before your code, right?

Comment: And Use `jQuery` instead `$` like this `jQuery(...).modal`

Comment: Yes, its top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

noConflict rolls back the `$` variable to what ever it's previous value was.  What this means is if another library was using the `$` variable as it's identifier, no conflict restores this association.  As a side effect though, `$` is no longer jQuery.  If you didn't intend for this to be the case, remove that line.  Otherwise, you will either need to start referring to jQuery in your code after that point, or put use the jQuery ready to pass in jQuery as `$` as it will for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();

    jQuery(document).ready(function($){ //<-- ready() will pass in jQuery as the first argument, so you can accept it as '$' and then just code like normal
        $("#openModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery.noConflict();

    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#openModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();

    jQ(document).ready(function(){
        jQ("#openModal").modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Tried all those, no difference. Thanks anyway.